# When/how do I Unregister a RegisteredWaitHandle

Tags: c#, .net, windows, threadpool

I'm using `ThreadPool.UnsafeRegisterWaitForSingleObject` (henceforth RWFSO) to asynchronously wait on a `Semaphore`. It returns me a `RegisteredWaitHandle` which I cannot easily `Unregister()`. I need to unregister these because the handle is keeping a reference to the delegate and its state object and my process is leaking memory with each handle. Eventually they do get finalized, but this takes far too long and puts far too much pressure on the GC, ballooning my process's private memory usage up into the 1.8GB range. I'm making a lot of asynchronous requests.

The semaphore is used to gate access to `HttpWebRequest`'s asynchronous implementation: `BeginGetRequestStream` and `BeginGetResponse`. If I don't use a semaphore, it keeps telling me "not enough free threads on the thread pool" because of the moronic way in which it was implemented. If I use blocking primitives like `semaphore.WaitOne()` then my thread pool will eventually be deadlocked and nothing will make progress.

RWFSO returns a `RegisteredWaitHandle` but this is useless to my calling thread as I need to `Unregister()` this handle only when the wait is completed; I have no cancellation scenario. I can't just pass the `RegisteredWaitHandle` instance to my delegate (via an out-of-band field set on the state object passed to the delegate) because the delegate could be completed on another thread before control even returns from RWFSO.

How do I safely and quickly `Unregister()` a `RegisteredWaitHandle`s when and only when its wait is completed?

Comment: Did you try P/Invoking `UnregisterWait` and variants (UnregisterWaitEx)?

Comment: No, but on what reference would I do that and from where? That's the main problem I'm having; trying to clean up these handles AFTER the wait is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the handle to the delegate via whatever mechanism works for you. If the handle is null by the time the delegate executes, have the delegate spin on waiting for the assignment. Don't worry about the trivial amount of CPU time used, because you can just put `Thread.Yield` in the loop. If it bothers you, you can use a lock.

Alternatively you can unregister the handles that are there, and let the GC clean up the few that lost the race.

Comment: Unfortunately, even though I `Unregister()` the handles, the GC doesn't reclaim them and the memory still leaks. I've tested this with CLRProfiler.exe and I see a bunch of `RegisteredWaitHandle` objects that live for the lifetime of the process.

Comment: @JamesDunne: What if you set the handler to `null` after you unregister it?

Comment: Yes, I'm setting the reference to `null` after I `Unregister()` it. Makes no difference.

Comment: Can the profiler tell you what objects are holding the references?

Comment: No actually, I just see that the `RegisteredWaitHandle` objects are still active at the end of the process.

Comment: This was the proper solution and I've resolved my issue. Turns out I don't have to worry about race conditions with the delegate being called before the RWFSO returns. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to tie up a thread waiting for the handle, why not just make the HTTP request synchronously?  What you are doing is actually tying up two threads per request (if I understand your implementation correctly), whereas just running your requests synchronously would take one thread per request (and could still be moderated using a semaphore or a constrained thread pool, if you need to throttle it).

Comment: I mean it as an answer to the broader problem.  It is acceptable to answer by saying "hey, you are running into trouble because you are doing it wrong", rather than answering the precise question that the user asked.  It is why we often ask for more context about the situation.

Comment: "If you are going to tie up a thread waiting for the handle" ... no. RWFSO registers a callback with the OS telling it to queue up a delegate to call on a worker threadpool thread in order to do the work when the wait is completed. The method returns nearly instantly and does not block the thread it was called on. The work queued up is just a simple call to start the real async I/O request.

Comment: You've updated your answer since my initial comment... just sayin' :)